# Get the current user's account name in Windows

Tags: windows, user-accounts

In Windows, how can I get the current user's account name ? ***NOTE:*** I'm asking for the "account name", not the username. These are two distinct, different things in Windows. The account name is what gets shown on the login screen and start menu, the username is the name registered with the OS for a user and is used to uniquely identify the user. The username is also what's returned by `Environment.UserName`, which is **not** what I'm looking for. (Side note, the username gets displayed on the Start menu and logon screen when no account name has been explicitly specified for the user.)

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Are you operating in an Active Directory environment, or standalone?

Comment: Standalone. Single user in a private workgroup.

Comment: You only want to do this for that single OS?

Comment: Well, Windows 7 is the only version I'm interested in at the moment, but I'd certainly like to know how to do it on other Windows versions as well.

Comment: Are you looking for script to achieve this?

Comment: I'm intending to use this functionality in a script. If it has to call another script to do it, that's fine. Is the account name a queryable property in Active Directory (or LDAP) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read the user's display (first and last) name on all versions of Windows reliably?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686201/how-do-you-read-the-users-display-first-and-last-name-on-all-versions-of-wind)