# Get logged on user's name or email on Windows 8 using C++ and WinAPIs

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, sessionid

On Windows 7 to retrieve the name of a logged on user I can do this:

```
LPTSTR pUserName = NULL;
DWORD dwcbSzUserName = 0;

//'dwSessID' = user session ID
if(WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwSessID, WTSUserName, &pUserName, &dwcbSzUserName))
{
    //Got user name in 'pUserName'
}

if(pUserName)
    WTSFreeMemory(pUserName);
```

But on Windows 8 it returns some abbreviated name, for instance, "john_000" when the actual user's name is "John A. Doe".

So what is the way to retrieve the name of the logged on user (and possibly their email) on Windows 8 with C++ using WinAPIs as it's shown at log-on screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get logged-in user's full name in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438634/how-to-get-logged-in-users-full-name-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [NetUserGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [USER_INFO_23](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get full name.

Something basically like:

```
    //Got user name in 'pUserName'
    NetUserGetInfo(NULL, pUserName, 23, my_USER_INFO_23);
    //Got display name in my_USER_INFO_23.usri23_full_name
```

Comment: Very nice, this is the way to get the full user name. But what about the email?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Are you talking about retrieving a Windows Live ID linked to the user account (if any) ?

Comment: I think a user ID is linked to the Live ID on Windows 8. If you have Windows 8, it shows as an email right next to your user icon on a logon screen. But that's OK, as long as I have a full user name I'd be fine. Thanks!

Comment: [Signing in to Windows 8 with a Windows Live ID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/26/signing-in-to-windows-8-with-a-windows-live-id.aspx)